# C++ Class constructor inside definition?

Tags: c++

Can I define a class constructor without using scopes (::) after it's definition?

I'll put it another way, Can I put the constructor inside the class definition???

Something similar to this:

```
MyClass {

public: 
    int attribute1;
    ...

    MyClass(int a) {
        attrbute1 = a;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, a constructor can be defined inline.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.

You can define any method inside the class declaration.

Comment: Except pure virtual ones :)

Comment: @StoryTeller ;) I don't think the OP will get the pun

Comment: @aletanis, probably. But that's why it's fun to mention ;)

Comment: ...and then they're implicitly inline.

Comment: @sellibitze I don't think the compiler cares where you put it, it just does what is best (inline or no inline). It's like the `inline` in front of methods, the compiler can (and *will* most of the times) ignore it.

Comment: I did not say that the compiler will inline them. I said that they are implicitly "inline functions". That's a difference. Check the one definition rule. I just wanted to make it clear that defining this inside a class that is possibly included into multiple translation units does not constitute an ODR violation because of their "inline" status. That's all.

Comment: Of course, the compiler won't ignore the inline keyword in general because there are different rules w.r.t. the ODR. But whether the function will actually be inlined is a different matter and I think that this is what you were referring to.

Comment: @sellibitze Yes, I was referring to the actual inlining, not to the other things the `inline` keyword does.

Comment: @SebastianRivas What trouble are you having? Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Terminology:   You want to **define** a C++ class constructor inside it's **declaration**
The answer is yes.
To find the answer you should not ask StackOverflow.  You should ask your C++ compiler.

Comment: Terminology: ...inside a class definition... A class declaration looks like this: `class MyClass;`

Answer (score 0):

Use an initialization list:

```
class MyClass 
{

private: 
    int attribute1;
    ...
public:
    MyClass(int a) : attribute1(a) {}
};
```

Comment: What? How is this an answer to his question?